# PHP: No database selected

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a strange error from my WAMP (PHP 5.5.12, MySQL 5.6.17).

The main error is: No database selected. 
I have two database tables here:

cities: id, cities

and

events (some fields are not included here): id, eventHeader, cityID.

So, there is my code.
This function displaays all the events, but in the database city is written as cityID, so I have another function that must convert cityID into city name.

```
public function viewEvents($conf) {

  // Connecting to DB with parameters from config file;
  $mysqli = $this->dbConnect($conf);

  // quering...
  $query = "SELECT * FROM events";
  $result = $mysqli->query($query);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($row['featured'] == 1) {
      $row['header'] = '<b>' . $row['header'] . '</b>';
    }

    // Getting City Name;
    $city = self::getCity($row['id']);

    // Echoing table with results here.
    echo '';
  }
  $result->free();
  $mysqli->close();
}
```

This function gets no error at all and works perfect. But the next one...

And this is my getCity($id):

```
 public function getCity($id) {

   $conf = $this->getConf();  // Getting config data (with db access);
   $mysqli = $this->dbConnect($conf);  // connecting to MySQL;

   // I'm echoing the possible mysql connection error here;


   // Quering...
   $query = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE id = '" . $id . "';";
   $result = $mysqli->query($query);

   // Echoing mysql query error here with die();

   $row = $result->fetch_array();
   $city = $row['city'];
   return $city;
}
```

So, this is dbConnect($conf){

```
public function dbConnect($conf) {
  $mysqli = mysqli_connect($conf['db-host'], $conf['db-usr'], $conf['db-psw'], $conf['db-name']);
  return $mysqli;
}
```

Despite of all my code variations I get the same error: `No database selected`. Is it possible, cause the first method works perfectly and they both uses the same `dbConnect()`?

Comment: Confirm that `$conf` has the correct values.

Comment: And you have verified that `$conf` contains all the expected values in your second function?

Comment: Sure! Cause it works in the first one.

Comment: `mysqli_query("use <<database>>");`, or set the database in the `mysqli` construct, or use `SELECT <<database>>.*`

Comment: Okay, that's what I get: `SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'cities'`. User described in config file has grant access to this database... The same happens while using user `root`

Comment: What if right below the mysqli_connect() you added a test for mysqli_connect_errno()? If that is not zero, then you can echo mysqli_connect_error() just to make sure the connection is successful, and if it isn't, why.

Comment: Just tried it. It is successful. No changes :(

Comment: So, if the first query works; maybe you could try passing $mysqli to getCity(). This way you would use the working connection instead of opening another connection inside the function (which I wonder if it's a good idea in any case). This won't solve the problem but it would help to spot where the error might be spawning.

Comment: Wow! That worked! Should be an answer. But I still do not get why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is a good idea to only have one connection during the request lifetime, so this might work for you:

```
static function dbConnect($conf)
{
    static $mysqli = null; 
    if ( $mysqli === null )
    {
        $mysqli = mysqli_connect($conf['db-host'], $conf['db-usr'], $conf['db-psw'], $conf['db-name']); 
    }
    return $mysqli; 
}

// Call this function like this:
$mysqli = self::dbConnect($conf);
```

Now, if you have a reliable method that returns the configuration parameters, you could even improve it like this to avoid having to pass the configuration every time. :

```
static function dbConnect()
{
    static $mysqli = null; 

    if ( $mysqli === null )
    {
        $conf = $this->getConf();
        $mysqli = mysqli_connect($conf['db-host'], $conf['db-usr'], $conf['db-psw'], $conf['db-name']); 
    }

    return $mysqli; 
}

// Call this function like this:
$mysqli = self::dbConnect();
```

This way you will always use only one connection to the database, no matter how many times you call dbConnect(). 
If the connection is already opened, it will return it; otherwise it will open the connection and then return it.

EDIT: **About why the second connection doesn't work**

In the `viewEvents()` function the call to `getCity()` uses the static version `self::getCity()`; while inside the `getCity()` function there are two calls to object methods: `$this->getConf()` and `$this->dbConnect()`.

I would suggest to change the call from `self::getCity()` to `$this->getCity()` inside the `viewEvents()` function.

Comment: This solution works perfectly, appreciated! But I am still clueless why the second method does not want to connect :( Maybe I should consider reinstalling WAMP server...

Comment: Oh wait! Take a look at the way you call getCity: **self::getCity()**. This is the static call to a class method, but then inside the method you are using **$this->getConf()** and **$this->dbConnect()**.  Try changing **self::getCity()** for **$this->getCity()**